# Childhood book about adventuring during dreams, young adult, young boy recruited to help a mission

Tags: identification-request

I read this book about 15 years ago. It was hardback - a big red book with gems in it. The book was about a boy who had powers when he dreamed - he could jump between worlds and was searching for something. He was recruited by someone. I think part of the book was based in the mountains.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please see the [identification-request wiki](/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] your question to add further details. For example, were there illustrations (on the front of the book, at the start of sections, scattered about throughout)? If so, what style were they? What approximate age was this aimed at (e.g. toddler and middle-grade are very different)? Does "big" refer to the cover's area or the thickness of the book? What language was it? Where were the mountains located?